# Parsing multiple groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have a HTML file(I can't use HTML AgilityPack) that I want to extract the id of a div(if it has one)

```
<div id="div1">Street ___________________ </div>
<div id="div2">CAP |__|__|__|__|__| number ______ </div>
<div id="div3">City _____________________ State |__|__|</div>
<div id="div4">City2 ____________________ State2 _____</div>
```

I have a pattern for extracting underscores **__** :  `[\ _]{3,}`

Now if I have a div in front of my underscores I want to extract it, if not I'll get only the underscores.

I have build so far this pattern `(<div id(.+?)>(\w)([\ _]{3,}/*))([\ _]{3,})`

The first part is build out of 3 groups
1 - a div tag, 2 - a label, 3 - underscores

1 - `<div id(.+?)>`, 2 - `(\w)` , 3 - `[\ _]{3,}/*`

The div with the id div2 will not take the id because it contains non-alfanumeric chars.

**Q:** What is wrong with my pattern ?

Desired matchs for the 4 divs:

```
<div id="div1">Street ___________________
______ 
<div id="div3">City _____________________
<div id="div4">City2 ____________________
_____
```

Comment: Aaaah... html parsing with a regex!!! http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/613130

Comment: @xanatos: Its not really HTML parsing because the requirements don't worry about nesting items which is the main problem with parsing via regex.

Comment: So you can have div WITHOUT id and div WITH id, and you want to extract the id (if present) and the content of these div(s), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\w` is just a single character, you probably want to say one or more - `\w+`.
- `/*` - zero or more `/`'s? I don't see where that fits in.
- One or more not `>`'s (i.e. `[^>]+`) is probably a better idea than `.+?`. `.+?` will try to stop at the first `>`, but will continue until it finds a string that matches, i.e.:

  ```
  <div id=1>this is not valid</div><div id=2>this is valid___</div>
  ```

  will match the whole string, instead of just from `<div id=2>`.
- As far as I can tell from your question, everything before the underscores should be optional.

Pattern:

```
(?:(<div id[^>]+>)(\w+))?([\ _]{3,})
```

[C# Test](https://ideone.com/BPrhIE).

Comment: I think you are missing a parenthesis in your pattern. If I add a ) : (?:(<div id([^>]+?)>(\w+))?([\ _|]{3,})(?:(\w+)([\ _|]{3,}))?) then in the second match I capture this string |__|__|__|__|__| witch is not alfanumeric.

Comment: Edited my answer, it should be closer to what you want now.

Comment: In this line "<div id="div3">City _____________________ State |__|__|</div>" it only captures "_____________________". "City" contains alphanumeric chars so it should have been matched.

Comment: Seems I accidentally left the escape characters there. Fixed.

Comment: This works better. If I want to allow spaces why doesn't it work if I add "\s" ? (\w\s+)

Comment: `\w\s+` means one word character and one or more white-space characters (not one or more of each). To say one or more of either, you can say `[\w\s]+` or `(\w|\s)+`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
string html = @"<div id=""div1"">Street ___________________ </div>
<div id=""div2"">CAP |__|__|__|__|__| number ______ </div>
<div id=""div3"">City _____________________ State |__|__|</div>
<div name=""hello"" id=""div4"">City _____________________ State |__|__|</div>
<div name=""house"">City _____________________ State |__|__|</div>
<div id=""notext""></div>";

var rx = new Regex(@"<div(?:(?: id=""(?<id>[^""]+)"")|[^>])*>(?<content>[^<]*)</div>", 
                   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var matches = rx.Matches(html);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var id = match.Groups["id"];
    var content = match.Groups["content"];

    Console.WriteLine("id present: {0}, id: {1}, text: {2}", 
                      id.Success, 
                      id.ToString(), 
                      content.ToString());
}
```

if it work I'll explain the regex (that is `<div(?:(?: id="(?<id>[^"]+)")|[^>])*>(?<content>[^<]*)</div>`)

Comment: <div id=""div2"">CAP **|__|__|__|__|__|** number ______ </div> - this is the second match and it contains non-alfanumeric chars | and _

Comment: @Misi AND??? It isn't clear what you want. My regex will simply extract all the <div> present in an html...

Comment: I don't want to extract the whole div if the content doesn't have alphanumeric characters. The Content for the 2nd match is : "CAP |__|__|__|__|__| number "

Comment: @Misi So you don't want the CAP line because it has the `|` ? Or you don't want only the CAP part and you want number ____ ?

Comment: And what should happen with the City line? (that has the State ___ part)?

Comment: I've edited my answer. "City" has all chars alphanumeric, "CAP |__|__|__|__|__| number" contains non-alphanumeric chars.